# Saving results of CPLEX with flow control (change data solve with regenerate)

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, cplex, opl, flow-control

After looking through stackoverflow + IBM forum + Alex Fleischer's How to Linkedin page, I manage to run my problem with script, changing a parameter at every iteration(flow control). However, I want to save the output of each iteration into a unique excel file. I read through the references, and manual/user guide but i am still not sure how to achieve it.

Before using the script, I used SheetWrite in the .dat file for each variable i want to save.

How can I do that while running the script so that it saves to a new excel file for every iteration?  (I have a finite number of iterations about 7 runs so I just need 7 files each run)

Thanks in advance..

```
main{
 var status = 0;
 thisOplModel.generate();
 var produce = thisOplModel;
 var best;
 var curr = Infinity;
 var maxdisp = produce.allowedwindisp;

 var ofile = new IloOplOutputFile("testresult.txt");

 while ( maxdisp>=1 ) {
    best = curr;
    writeln();
    writeln("Solve with maxdisp = ",maxdisp);
    if ( cplex.solve() ) {
    curr = cplex.getObjValue();
    writeln("OBJECTIVE: ",curr);
    ofile.writeln("Objective with maxdisp = ", maxdisp, " is ", curr);        
    } 
    else {
      writeln("No solution!");
      break;
    }

    // prepare next iteration
    var def = produce.modelDefinition;
    var data = produce.dataElements;

    if ( produce!=thisOplModel ) {
    produce.end();
    }

    produce = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);
    maxdisp--;
    data.allowedwindisp = maxdisp;
    produce.addDataSource(data);
    produce.generate();
    }    
    ofile.close();
    status;}
```

this is what i did to change the variable at each iteration, but i am not sure how to link to write a new excel file from each iteration.

EDIT this is my solution to achieve a new excel file for each run with data changed (modified the file names to be more inline with Alex's examples):
this is the main.mod, i will change the variable called delta in the code

```
    main{
 var status
 var source = new IloOplModelSource("sub.mod");
 var cplex = new IloCplex();
 var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);
 var best;
 var current = Infinity; 


   for(var delta = 0;delta<=3;delta++)
  {
    var opl = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);
    var data2= new IloOplDataElements();
    data2.fileName="reference_filename"+delta+".xlsx";
    opl.addDataSource(data2);
    var data1 = new IloOplDataSource("datafile4Input_param.dat");
    opl.addDataSource(data1);
    var data3 = new IloOplDataElements();
    data3.delta_from_reference_input = delta;
    opl.addDataSource(data3)

    opl.generate();
    best = current;
    writeln();
    writeln("Solve with maxdisp = ",maxdisp);
    cplex.tilim = 3600;

    if (cplex.solve()) {
       current = cplex.getObjValue();
       writeln("OBJECTIVE: ",current);
       opl.postProcess();

    } 
    else {
       writeln("No solution");
    }
    opl.end();
}  
    status;
}
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should use SheetWrite in submodels dat part and do not forget to call opl.postProcess in the main script

Comment: thanks alex, i did see that post.
how do i do so to not overwrite the solutions to the file defined in the .dat file?

because in the .dat file, Sheetconnection is to a specific excel file to get all the input parameters. when i do it one-by-one, it will write into the sheet in the defined locations. 

however, when i loop i want the outputs to be stored in separate sheets... thanks in advance..

Comment: Instead of SheetConnection Sheet1("file.xls"); you should use SheetConnection Sheet1(filename); with filename a string that you set from the main script. In https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-opl-alex-fleischer/ you may use Change some data and solve again with regenerate

Comment: I looked at all the references... if i am interpreting what you said correctly..you are suggesting is to save the model as submodel.mod and do the flow control as the main.mod... and then similar to how i change the variable at each iteration, i change the filename to save at each iteration...

i tried but i failed. i tried to set the filename as a string in the submodel.mod, the error says filename not defined..

a work around without exporting to excel is to
writeln all the variables/ array i want to save.. but i hope to be able to save to a unique excel each time..

Comment: See https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=3c823976-4bc5-41b1-aa03-cfdb64bcb2ba&ps=25 where you can see how to change the string in SheetWrite, the same way you could change the string parameter in SheetConnection

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59074711/ilog-cplex-opl-dynamic-excel-sheet-referencing/59273058#59273058